# Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = NULL) : new columns would leave holes after existing columns

Tags: r

I am trying to check the correlation between a discharge value column and 92 columns of independent variables.  Right now I am trying to use a for loop and the cortest() function to see which column returns the highest correlation coefficient.  Here is my code as of now:

```
csv1 <- 
    read.csv("Z:/hhm/CDOT_Western_CO_Flow_Equations/Regional_Equations/OLS/wrm_work/Table1Values.csv",
                  header = TRUE, sep = ",")
    test1 <- cor.test(csv1$Q2, csv1$Outlet_Elevation, method = "kendall")
    y_cols <- csv1[-c(1:49)] ##Isolate the indep variables I want to check for correlation
    Q2 <- csv1$Q2  ##Isolate discharge values from master csv
    test_frame <- data.frame(Q2,y_cols)  ##Combine discharge column and variable columns

    result <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 1, nrow = length(y_cols)))  ##Create matrix for results

    for (i in 1:length(y_cols)) {
      test2 <- cor.test(test_frame$Q2, test_frame[,i], method = "kendall")
      result[i] <- test2[["tau"]]
    }
```

I feel like I am pretty close, but I can't shake this specific error:
"Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = NULL) :
new columns would leave holes after existing columns"

I believe this error has to do with after the first cortest, when it starts looping it cannot save the results from the last test?  I have tried many answers from other stack overflow questions with the same error code, but the examples are for very different codes.[test_frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeLav.png)

Any ideas on what is the problem with my code?
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some data in order to make the code reproducible.

Comment: Q2    Outlet_Elevation    PERIM    ELEVMIN    LEVEMAX    RELIEF    MEAN                 38.4    3171.7    39763.7    3171.66    3834.97    663.32    3427.78                                382.0    2665.4    272506.02    2665.4    3942.09    1276.69    3101.29                             189.4    2686.69    124212.35    2686.32    3774.89    1088.57    2985.03                     This is a small section of "test_frame".  Thanks!

Comment: Solved!                                                                                                                                       '''result <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 3, nrow = ncol(test_frame)))
colnames(result) <- c("tau", "x_data", "y_data")


for (i in 1:ncol(y_cols)) {
  test2 <- cor.test(test_frame$Q2, test_frame[,i], method = "kendall")
  tau <- test2$estimate
  result[i,1] <- tau
  result[i,2] <- colnames(test_frame)[1]
  result[i,3] <- colnames(test_frame)[i+1]
}'''